# Macro to move data with changing date

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this isn't explained overly well, im a macro newbie so im not sure if this one is even possible..

I'm looking to create a weekday table for some simple statistic reporting that automatically creates a new row each day, and removes the oldest, showing the data for the current day and 6  days previous. Ideally i'd like the current day at the top of the table, and each day the entered data in the corresponding row moves down 1 row creating space for the new day's stats.

As some background info on what im trying to do.. im basically creating a friendly UI display (offline HTML) of the data recorded in a very simple 5 column (stats) by 7 row (weekdays)  table. This database will need to be updated by multiple people with limited technical ability, so im basically trying to make it as easy as possible for them to enter stats each day without having to worry about also updating to correct dates and making sure they are replacing the right days data etc. In theory, it would be great to automate the process of updating the table each day to create space for them to enter the current days data, pushing yesterdays data down one row (and if the cell ranges for the whole table always the same, it should allow me to automate the updates to the offline HTML display as well).

Any ideas?

Comment: The table will ALWAYS be 7 rows by 5 columns, right? You're not adding rows to it as you add days, you're removing the oldest and adding a new one, right?

Answer (score 0):

First give a name to the date header cell. (Click the cell. Look at the top left of the screen where the cell coordinates appear. "A1", "B2", etc...
In that textbox, type the header name: "MyDateHeader"

then, use this macro (you can add it to the workbook open event, or activate)

```
Sub YourMacro()

    Dim DateHeader As Range
    Set DateHeader = Range("MyDateHeader")

    Dim FirstDateCell As Range
    Set FirstDateCell = DateHeader.Offset(1, 0)


    Dim MyDay As Integer, MyMonth As Integer, MyYear As Integer
    Dim CurrDay As Integer, CurrMonth As Integer, CurrYear As Integer

    MyDay = Day(FirstDateCell.Value)
    MyMonth = Month(FirstDateCell.Value)
    MyYear = Year(FirstDateCell.Value)

    CurrDay = Day(Date)
    CurrMonth = Month(Date)
    CurrYear = Year(Date)


    If (MyDay <> CurrDay) Or (MyMonth <> CurrMonth) Or (MyYear <> CurrYear) Then
        FirstDateCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        DateHeader.Offset(1, 0).Value = Date 'Careful, FirstDateCell has moved down.
        DateHeader.Offset(8, 0).EntireRow.Clear
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
Sub WeekdayTable()

Dim tbl As Range
Dim r As Integer

Set tbl = Range("A1:E7") 'Define your table, 5 columns x 7 rows. Modify as needed.

For r = tbl.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    tbl.Rows(r).Value = tbl.Rows(r - 1).Value
Next

'empty out row 1
tbl.Rows(1).Clear

'Assuming the column 1 contains valid DATE values, _
' we can use the DateAdd function to print the next date:
tbl.Cells(1, 1) = DateAdd("d", 1, tbl.Cells(2, 1))

End Sub
```